# AngularJS is not updating a select after an option was deleted

Tags: angularjs, select, ng-options

Angular is not updating the options of a select box after it was deleted. I have to refresh the view to see the updated options. Thank you.

My view

```
form(ng-controller="FormRemoveStudentController", name="formAddStudentForm", novalidate)
    div.combine
        label.default.top(for="student") Select a student
        select.default(ng-model="student.id", ng-options="s.id as s.name for s in students")
            option(value="") I would like to remove...
    div.combine
        button.default.blue(ng-click="removeStudent()") Submit
```

My controller

```
app.controller('FormRemoveStudentController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.student = {};
    $scope.students = [];

    var setStudents = function (data) {
        $scope.students = data.students || [];
        console.log("Students has updated.")
    };

    var errorStudents = function () {
        $scope.students = [];
        console.error("DATABASE ERROR");
    };

    $http.get(url).success(setStudents).error(errorStudents);


    $scope.removeStudent = function () {
        var finalURL = url + $scope.student.id;

        // $http.delete(final); this is supposed to work if the server was fine.
        conn.delete(finalURL); // Delete the option

        $scope.student = {};
        $scope.formAddStudentForm.$setPristine();

        $http.get(url).success(setStudents).error(errorStudents); // Reload the options.
    };
}])
```

Comment: change to `option(value="?")`

Comment: What syntax is your view written in?

Comment: ng-options by default adds a value `option(value="?")` and removes it once a value is selected... so you can use this trick

Answer (score 0):

Set the ng-model to be `student` on your select and have it default to null instead of an empty object. 
In your remove function,  reset `student` to null as well

Also ensure you update your ng-options appropriately